# How to capture pid of a linux daemon run from init.d

Tags: linux, pid

I have started a service daemon  , by running the binary(written in C++) through script file stored rc5.d .

But I am not sure how to capture the pid of the daemon process and store it in pid file in /var/run/.pid  . So that I can use the pid for termination.
How can I do this?

Comment: Not so sure this belongs on SF. It sounds like he's written a service and wants to ship it with a proper init script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `start-stop-daemon(8)` with the `--pidfile` argument in your init script. Have your program write its PID to a specified location (usually determined in a configuration file).

What you have to look out for is stale PID files, for instance, if a lock file persisted across a reboot. That logic is best implemented in the init script itself, hence the `--exec` option to `start-stop-daemon`.

E.g, if `/var/run/foo.pid` is `1234`, and `/proc/1234/exe` isn't your service, the lock file is stale and should be quietly removed, allowing the service to start normally.

As far as your application goes, just make sure the location of the lockfile is configurable, and some means exists to tell the init script where to put it.

For instance: (sample: /etc/default/foo) :

```
PIDFILE=/var/run/foo.pid
OTHEROPTION=foo
```

Then in /etc/init.d/foo :

```
[ -f /etc/default/foo ] && . /etc/default/foo
```

Again, other than writing to the file consistently, all of this logic should be handled outside of your application.

Comment: @Tim Post but this option only checks whether to start the daemon or not if it is already running. I want is there any standard way in writing the pid to /var/run/

Comment: @Sirish - Just test to see if the file exists, create it if it doesn't, write the PID and close it. If it exists, there's a very good chance that the server is already running. Testing for stale lockfiles is much easier to do in the init script.

Comment: @Sirish - Updated my answer, I _think_ its what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the port the program has open, use `fuser` command to determine the pid.

Answer (score 1):

You could go about more than one way:

1. In your program use [getpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid) to write it to a configurable file (perhaps looking in ENV)
2. Use $! after starting the program (this doesn't work for me on archlinux though :-?)
3. After starting the program, use [pidof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof)